# Illustrator: subselect and change text objects

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Asking because I couldn't find this googling:

I have data plots that consist of many small numbers. What I would want to do, ideally, is select a portion of text and graphic elements, then adjust text sizes and fonts within that selected area. However, tools to do this only show if **only** text elements are selected.

How do I change these text styles, while not touching all remaining - unselected - text? Is it possible to subselect only text objects somehow / easily?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust things in the **Character Panel** even if text and objects are selected. Simply view/use the Character Panel (`Window > Type > Character`)

You can also merely select text object by using the **Select Menu**. Simply choose `Select > Objects > Text Objects` and all the text will be selected (as an object, not live editing mode). And from there you can again use the Character panel, but the Control bar or Properties Panel may also work with only text objects selected.

Then, there's the **Direct Selection Tool** (White arrow) which will allow you to individually select objects (text objects) within a group without breaking the group.

Comment: `Select > Objects > Text Objects` doesn't show for me. After selecting my objects and then looking at that menu it shows only `All Text Objects` - which seems utterly useless - which part did I misunderstand? is it a versioning issue?

Comment: It's the same thing, Adobe has merely added specifics for Point and Area Text. "all" will select both Point Text and Area Text. Not sure why that's "useless".

Comment: because I the goal here is to subselect certain text. I guess the easiest is to just copy the files into a new document

Comment: There's no mention of sub-selection *text objects* in your question... As I read things you wanted to select text object and *not* the graphic objects.... You didn't explain that you needed to select only *specific* text objects. And there's no real method to select only *some* text objects if they are all on the same layer.

Answer (score 0):

Click and drag a selection with the Selection Tool (black arrow). When you have text and other graphics selected the text tools across the top in the control bar will not be available.

To access the tools for changing text size and font go to Window> Type> Character to open the Character panel. You will be able to change text-specific attributes without modifying the other selected graphics.